# ERROR: ValidationError - The AWSEBDockerrunVersion key in the Dockerrun.aws.json file is not valid or is not included

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerrun.aws.json

I tried to run Multicontainer Docker in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Here is my Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "command": ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"
        ],
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "JAEGER_AGENT_HOST",
                "value": "jaeger"
            },
            {
                "name": "STOREFRONT_URL",
                "value": "http://localhost:3000/"
            },
            {
                "name": "DASHBOARD_URL",
                "value": "http://localhost:9000/"
            }
        ],
        "memory": 512,
        "image": "saleor-platform_api",
        "essential": true,
        "links": [
               "api",
               "POSTGRES_USER",
               "redis",
               "worker",
               "jaeger"
            ],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "containerPath": "/app/tests",
                "sourceVolume": "_SaleorTests"
            },
            {
                "containerPath": "/app/media",
                "sourceVolume": "Saleor-Media"
            },
            {
                "containerPath": "/app/saleor",
                "sourceVolume": "_Saleor"
            },
            {
                "containerPath": "/app/templates",
                "sourceVolume": "Saleor-templates"
            }
        ],
        "name": "api",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 8000,
                "hostPort": 8000
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
                "value": "saleor"
            },
            {
                "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
                "value": "saleor"
            }
        ],
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 256,
        "image": "library/postgres:11.1-alpine",
        "links": [
               "api",
               "POSTGRES_USER",
               "redis",
               "worker",
               "jaeger"
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql",
                "sourceVolume": "Saleor-Db"
            }
        ],
        "name": "db",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 5432,
                "hostPort": 5432
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "essential": true,
        "image": "jaegertracing/all-in-one",
        "name": "jaeger",
        "memory": 256,
        "links": [
               "api",
               "POSTGRES_USER",
               "redis",
               "worker",
               "jaeger"
        ],
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 5775,
                "hostPort": 5775,
                "protocol": "udp"
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 6831,
                "hostPort": 6831,
                "protocol": "udp"
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 6832,
                "hostPort": 6832,
                "protocol": "udp"
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 5778,
                "hostPort": 5778
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 16686,
                "hostPort": 16686
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 14268,
                "hostPort": 14268
            },
            {
                "containerPort": 9411,
                "hostPort": 9411
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "essential": true,
        "image": "library/redis:5.0-alpine",
        "memory": 256,
        "links": [
               "api",
               "POSTGRES_USER",
               "redis",
               "worker",
               "jaeger"
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "containerPath": "/data",
                "sourceVolume": "Saleor-Redis"
            }
        ],
        "name": "redis",
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 6379,
                "hostPort": 6379
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": [
            "celery",
            "-A",
            "saleor",
            "worker",
            "--app=saleor.celeryconf:app",
            "--loglevel=info"
        ],
        "image": "saleor-platform_worker",
        "memory": 256,
        "essential": true,
        "links": [
               "api",
               "POSTGRES_USER",
               "redis",
               "worker",
               "jaeger"
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "containerPath": "/app/media",
                "sourceVolume": "Saleor-Media"
            }
        ],
        "name": "worker"
    }
],
"family": "",
"volumes": [

    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "./saleor/saleor/"
        },
        "name": "_Saleor"
    },
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "./saleor/templates/"
        },
        "name": "Saleor-templates"
    },
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "./saleor/tests/"
        },
        "name": "_SaleorTests"
    },
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "saleor-media"
        },
        "name": "Saleor-Media"
    },
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "saleor-db"
        },
        "name": "Saleor-Db"
    },
    {
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "saleor-redis"
        },
        "name": "Saleor-Redis"
    }


]
```

}

However, when I typed "eb local run", it gives me the error "ERROR: ValidationError - The AWSEBDockerrunVersion key in the Dockerrun.aws.json file is not valid or is not included."
Does anyone know why? Thanks

Comment: Can you double check your EB platform? Are you sure its multidocker, and not single-docker?

Comment: How do I check whether my EB platform is multidocker and single-docker? I also suspect that I am using a single-docker EB. However, when I use "eb init", it never asks me whether I want a multidocker or single-docker. Thanks

Comment: You can check in the confing file, `cat ./.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` or `eb platform show`

Comment: I think i am using a single-docker right now. Here is my config.yml
https://github.com/hkbluesky/settings/blob/master/config.yml
How do I change it to multidocker? Thanks

Comment: Strange, it does not show which docker. You can re-select it using `eb platform select`.

Comment: After "eb platform select", it seems running now. But it possibly takes a moment.

Comment: Glad to hear. I will make an answer then for future reference if you don't mind :-)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that a EB Docker platform was **incorrect** and/or not chosen.

The **solution** was to select a correct platform using:

```
eb platform select
```

Comment: The platform is correct now. But the project still does not work. Should I continue comments here?

Comment: @JerryZhang I think new question with new error messages would be warranted. This will allow others to also contribute and see the new question.

Comment: Yes. I will create a new post for my new question. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63571928/from-docker-compose-yml-to-dockerrun-aws-json
This is my new question. If you can have a look, it will be great.

Comment: I published another post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572956/difficult-fields-from-docker-compose-yml-to-dockerrun-aws-json
I will really appreciate your help If you have time to have a look.