# from docker-compose.yml to Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerrun.aws.json

I manually translate my `docker-compose.yml` to Dockerrun.aws.json. However, it did not work quite right.

But I find out that when I typed `eb local run`, eb CLI tool added a file called docker-compose.yml to the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder. It seems that eb CLI tool tried to translate Dockerrun.aws.json to  `docker-compose.yml`. Since I already have a working docker-compose.yml, could I just replace `docker-compose.yml` in the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder with my correct `docker-compose.yml`? Doing manual translation is tedious and I made some mistakes. Does anyone know the quick way to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [container-transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform) to convert the file?

Comment: I tried container-transform, but the result is not very good. I am still trying to figure out which parts are wrong in the translation. I just feel beanstalk does not need Dockerrun.aws.json. If it can use docker-compose.yml directly, it will be much easier.

Comment: Sadly, EB does not support docker-compose natively. You have to convert it to `Dockerrun.aws.json`. the EB CLI maybe trying to do it poorly, but it still has to be `Dockerrun.aws.json` v2.

Comment: I see. I will post my files shortly and I want to ask how to translate several places in my files. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572956/difficult-fields-from-docker-compose-yml-to-dockerrun-aws-json
This is my new post if you have time to have a look. Thanks